# Use Python library in Slurm job

Tags: python-3.7, slurm, pythonpath

I want to run a job on Slurm and my Python script needs the `evaluate` package which I have on my local machine. I don't know if I could change the Python path on the server to match the one on my local machine, and if I could I'm afraid I might break the system.

So I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883018/how-to-install-python-package-module-in-slurm), and included a `requirements.txt` file with just `evaluate==0.1.2` in it, and I get even more errors:

```
load GCC/10.2.0 (PATH, MANPATH, INFOPATH, LIBRARY_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, STD COMP VARS) 
load ROCM/5.1.1 (PATH, MANPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH)
Set INTEL compilers as MPI wrappers backend
load mkl/2018.4 (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
load PYTHON/3.7.4 (PATH, MANPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, PYTHONHOME, PYTHONPATH) 
/var/spool/slurmd/job216863/slurm_script: line 12: virtualenv: command not found
/var/spool/slurmd/job216863/slurm_script: line 16: /env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement evaluate==0.1.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for evaluate==0.1.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eval_comet.py", line 1, in <module>
    from evaluate import load
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'evaluate'
```

Comment: Hi, the error is very simple. `virtualenv` command is not found. First tell me which Python version you want to install? Do you know anything about Python versions? Like the latest is 3.12.

Comment: I have Python 3.10.5 installed on my local machine. I would like the path on the server to match that on the local machine because that's where all of the libraries are installed.

Comment: Ok i will write an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, the Python version on HPCs are old. My Uni's HPC cluster has Python 3.7. If you wish to create a Python virtual environment (not conda) with a newer version, then there is a trick.

Activate the Anaconda Module, some system uses `Module load` and some uses `load` depending on your organisation.

```bash
[s.1915438@sl2 ~]$ module load anaconda/2021.05
[s.1915438@sl2 ~]$ conda create -n surrogate python=3.8
```

Here I created a Conda environment named `surrogate` with Python 3.8. Here, you can choose any version of your choice. Now you can activate the Conda environment and check the Python version.

```bash
[s.1915438@sl2 ~]$ source activate surrogate
(modulus) [s.1915438@sl2 ~]$ which python
~/.conda/envs/surrogate/bin/python
(surrogate) [s.1915438@sl2 ~]$ python --version
Python 3.8.13
```

Now navigate to the directory where you want to install your Python virtual environment and install the virtual environment using the following command.

```bash
(surrogate) [s.1915438@sl2 s.1915438]$ mkdir modulus_pysdf
(surrogate) [s.1915438@sl2 s.1915438]$ cd modulus_pysdf/
(surrogate) [s.1915438@sl2 modulus_pysdf]$ python3 -m venv modulus_pysdf
```

Logout (ctrl + D) from the server to exit the Conda environment and then login again. Remember, in my case the path to the Python virtual environment was `/scratch/s.1915438/modulus_pysdf`.

This is how I will activate the Python virtual environment.

```bash
[s.1915438@sl2 ~]$ cd /scratch/s.1915438
[s.1915438@sl2 s.1915438]$ cd modulus_pysdf/
[s.1915438@sl2 modulus_pysdf]$ source modulus_pysdf/bin/activate
```

Now I can check the Python version and the path.

```bash
(modulus_pysdf) [s.1915438@sl2 modulus_pysdf]$ python --version
Python 3.8.13
(modulus_pysdf) [s.1915438@sl2 modulus_pysdf]$ which python
/scratch/s.1915438/modulus_pysdf/modulus_pysdf/bin/python
```

As usual, I can install any package using `pip`. For example, to install `evaluate` you can download it from `PyPI`

```bash
pip install evaluate
```

Or if you have a `requirements.txt` file then you can do this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70666213/14598633) for more details.

```bash
cat requirements.txt | grep -Eo '(^[^#]+)' | xargs -n 1 pip install
```